# Pose mirroring wrong

Tags: armature, mirror, pose-mode

Blender newbie here. I have a problem mirroring poses that's giving me a headache.
When I mirror, for example, the left leg, the right leg isn't
correctly mirrored; it's rotated for some reason.

I've read possible solutions and watched some videos,
but I still get bad results.

This is what I do:
First, I create the bones I need:

[image]

I placed the 3D cursor at (0, 0, 0).
I select all of them except the torso and head bones. I key <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, then <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, then <kbd>X</kbd>, and finally <kbd>Enter</kbd>
to create a mirrored copy. Afterwards, I key <kbd>W</kbd> to open the *Edit Mode Specials Menu* and select to *Flip Names*.

[image]

Once that is done, I go to *Pose Mode* and move some bones on the right side:

[image]

Then, with those bones selected, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste mirrored,
but this is what happens:

[image]

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem.
For every bone in *Edit Mode*, I had to set the *Roll* value to *0*.
Then, for some bones with *Bone Constraints*, I had to set the *Pole Angle* to *0* or *180*.
Finally, I had to clear parents for my meshes and parent them to the bones again.

Comment: As you have discovered, mirroring bones like this will lead to incorrect rolls. There is a symmetry mode in edit mode that will help with roll angles etc if you do this again. After flipping the names, you should enable symmetry on the x axis and grab and release all the bones on one side so sync all the properties with the other.