# Is there a way to properly mirror an animation?

Tags: animation, mirror

I've already searched and searched and none of the answers to this question have helped me. I have an animation of a character moving right, and I need to flip it so that he's moving left. I've tried copying and pasting flipped both in the action editor and the 3D view and neither works right. My bone names are all correct with .L and .R for left and right respectively.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the [.blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47672).

Comment: One hack I can think of is duplicating the armature, mirroring it and then using constraints on the original armature bones to snap to the mirrored counterparts (copy location, IK etc depends on the rig). Then you just bake it to flat animation that you can export. Takes a while to setup but would work on all your animations at once. Sorry no time to make this an actual answer and maybe there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Add an *Empty* and place it in the same position where the origin point of your armature is. In *Object Mode* select your rig, then an *Empty* and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
[image]

Now select the *Empty* and scale it by -1 (<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>-1</kbd>).
Note that this may not be the proper way to do it. I think you should find the *root bone* (which controls all the other bones location) and rotate it by 180 degrees.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, but this is being exported to Unity, so I need the real thing. :\

Answer (score 0):

Pose mirroring through copy / mirrored pasting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> ) works using the bone's axes.

If you haven't build your rig properly with the right symmetrization, then the bones axes won't be good and the mirroring will not work correctly.

To fix this, you have to change the bones rolls in edit mode, then remake the meshes's Armature Deform Modifier.

You can see a way to do this [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/58035/53447). You can also use the Recalculate Roll menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> in edit mode).