# Mirroring an animation accurately without creating extra keyframes

Tags: animation, mirror, fcurves, actions

Lots of questions about the same thing but they can be solved by simply pasting the pose x-flipped or by mirroring the keyframes in the Fcurve editor. However, for an animation that crosses the global X-axis (in my case strafing with root motion), this doesn't work.

[This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89296/is-there-a-way-to-properly-mirror-an-animation) is the closest thing so far, but like that asker my model will be exported to game engine, so a Blender-specific hack like that doesn't work. I've also found that in object mode I can select the armature, right click and select "Mirror X", but again this doesn't actually create a new animation and is limited to within Blender.

I've also found a script that will automatically keyframe X-flipped poses, however it also fails when the animation crosses the global X-axis, and furthermore it adds more keyframes than the input has and makes a big mess of the animation data, not to mention that adding extra keyframes messes up the interpolation on the F-curves. This seems to be a bug in the 'Available' keying set; for example if only one location axis is keyed, it will create keys for all axes despite only one channel actually being available.

How can I create a new action that is an exact (**EXACT**, not just pose-flipped, and without adding a bunch of unnecessary keyframes and making a mess of the animation data) mirror of a different action?